# Replace file path in all m3u's in directory

Tags: command-line, playlists

I've created a lot of "file path relative" (so they work on my phone as well) playlists in my Soundtrack folder but also elsewhere I believe and now have decided to rename my classical subfolder from "European" to "Western".

How can I make sure that each of the file paths is changed from
`../../Classical/European/[...]` to `../../Classical/Western/[...]` ?

I usually manually edit those files in Gedit.

All play-lists and music files are in some sub-folder of `/home/gratis/Music`

Comment: I don't get it. It looks like you want to rename a single directory. Can you explain how it is different? Are you talking about symlinks?

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the content of one of your .m3u files (or just a couple lines)  followed by those same lines edited to look the way you want them to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically the same approach as [suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/912112/85695) by Markus, just a slightly different syntax:

```
shopt -s globstar
perl -pe 's|((\.\./){2}Classical)/European/|$1/Western/|' ~/Music/**/*m3u
```

#### Explanation

- `shopt -s globstar` : this command activates bash's globstar option which makes `**` match all files and zero or more directories and  subdirectories. So, `~/Music/**/*m3u` will match all files (and directories) under `~/Music` or its subdirectories whose name ends in `m3u`.
- `perl -pe` : **p**rint each input line after applying the script given by `-e` to it.
- `s|((\.\./){2}Classical)/European/|$1/Western/|` : this is the substitution operator. Its general format is `s|foo|bar|` which will replace `foo` with `bar`. The more common form is `s/foo/bar/` but the delimiters can be any character. Since here we want to match something that contains `/`, I used `|` as the delimiter for clarity.
- `(\.\./){2}` : match `../` exactly two times. Because `.` means "any character" in regular expressions, they need to be escaped (`\.`). The parentheses here are used to group the `\.\./` together so the `{2}` applies to the group.
- `((\.\./){2}Classical)` : the parentheses here are again used to forma a group but this time it is so that we can refer to the group as `$1` on the right hand side of the substitution. That's why we replace with `$1/Western`, because `$1` is whatever was matched by `(\.\./){2}Classical`.

If that does what you want, run it again with the `-i` option to make it edit the original file:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's|((\.\./){2}Classical)/European/|$1/Western/|' ~/Music/**/*m3u
```

The `-i.bak` will cause it to edit the file and create a backup of the original with the same name and the extension `.bak`.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace all occurrences of this string in all files using this perl one-liner:

```
perl -i -pe 's/\.\.\/\.\.\/Classical\/European\//..\/..\/Classical\/Western\//g' /home/gratis/Music/*/*.m3u
```

Be careful as this command will replace all occurrences of `../../Classical/European/[...]` to `../../Classical/Western/[...]` in all `.m3u` files in all subfolders of `/home/gratis/Music/` but not `/home/gratis/Music/` itself.

If you just want to check the output remove the `-i` from the command. This way the command does not alter the files.

Comment: thanks for the answer but for whatever reason this did not work. terdon's suggestion did though